# android + mapview large amount of marquers

Tags: android, performance, android-mapview

I have been following the [hello mapview tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html)

In the tutorial they use a custom implementation of the ItemizedOverlay class.
I tried using this approach but I am getting very poor performance when I add a large number of OverlayItems.

This leads me to think that the tutorial I used is not best suited for my needs. Can anyone point me to a tutorial or documentation on what I should use when I need to add a large number of markers (<500) on a mapview ?

Cheers !

Comment: I cannot point you to an example, but I agree that `ItemizedOverlay` is designed for fewer items than that.

Comment: in the end I implemented my own version of Overlay. I had to override the Draw method and calculate wich elements should be visible according to the map's current location.

Comment: thanks yann, I had the same issue with 400 markers. I will try your suggestion.